# What do the Type Parameter Names P and R mean and how are they used?

Tags: java, generics

I recently posted a question on SO ([How do I use double dispatch to analyze intersection of graphic primitives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400582/how-do-i-use-double-dispatch-to-analyze-intersection-of-graphic-primitives)) in which one of the answers (which I have accepted) used generics including `<P>` and `<R>`. They aren't in the Oracle docs [Java generics list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) but I have seen them used elsewhere (e.g. [Generics overkill in visitor pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698253/generics-overkill-in-visitor-pattern) ) - are they specific to the visitor pattern? And why are both `super` and `extends` used?

The code is:

```
public interface ShapeVisitor<P, R> { 
    R visitRect(Rect rect, P param);
    R visitLine(Line line, P param);
    R visitText(Text text, P param);
}

public interface Shape {
    <P, R> R accept(P param, ShapeVisitor<? super P, ? extends R> visitor);
    Shape intersectionWith(Shape shape);
}

public class Rect implements Shape {

    public <P, R> R accept(P param, ShapeVisitor<? super P, ? extends R> visitor) {
        return visitor.visitRect(this, param);
    }

    public Shape intersectionWith(Shape shape) {
        return shape.accept(this, RectIntersection);
    }

    public static ShapeVisitor<Rect, Shape> RectIntersection = new ShapeVisitor<Rect, Shape>() {
        public Shape visitRect(Rect otherShape, Rect thisShape) {
            // TODO...
        }
        public Shape visitLine(Line otherShape, Rect thisShape) {
            // TODO...
        }
        public Shape visitText(Text otherShape, Rect thisShape) {
            // TODO...
        }
    };
}
```

and I'd be grateful for

Comment: This is a double dispatch pattern

Comment: Yes - that's why I accepted it as an answer to my question about double dispatch :-). It was the use of generics that I need guidance on..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names `P` and `R` are just identifiers. Judging by how they're used, I think they mean "Parameter" and "Return Value", respectively.

Now, in the `Shape.accept` method, parameters can be made to be contra-variant, that's why you see `super` with `P`, and a return value co-variant, and that's why you see `extends` with `R` there.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a class:

```
public class MyComparable<R>{

    public boolean compare(R r1, R r2){
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

you are just indicating that you need to use two objects of the same Class.

to initialize that class you would use

```
List<String> strings = fillStrings();
int i = 1;
while(i < strings.size()){
    boolean comparePreviousWithThis = new MyComparable<String>().compare(strings.get(i-1),strings.get(i));
}
```

so you are only specifying the kind of relation that the objects of this class will have.

Comment: This doesn't address the question asked.